# Python Threading & queue

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I'm new to python programming so sorry if the question is stupid...

I wrote a script to check status for 2 server every 5 seconds and I call the function in the following way:

```py
while1 :
   f1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
   f1.start()

   f2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
   f2.start()

   time.sleep(5)
```

In this way everything works fine: the 2 threads start at the same time and end with a different duration but always within the 5 seconds.
I would like to avoid one of the threads (for example f1) starting again if the previous run (always f1) was not finished. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a starter, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The latter in particular because it explains that your question is bad: It could be answered with a simple "Yes.". BTW: Have you checked what functions a `threading.Thread` instance supports? Maybe one of them fits your needs...

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the threading function online. I managed to find `.is_alive()` which looks like the thing you are after.

For example;

```
f1 = None
f2 = None

while1 :

   #If f1 is not a thread or it is not an active thread...
   if (f1 == None or not f1.is_alive()):
      f1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
      f1.start()

   f2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
   f2.start()

   time.sleep(5)
```